# Pandas replacing negative values with opposite sign for a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to visualize buy and sell transactions with matplotlib.

BEFORE that, I need to work on some columns.

In my dataset containing the sell and buy of a date, I've managed to isolate the buy and sell transactions with

```
sell = df[df.side == 1]
buy = df[df.side == 0]
```

As the column vale of 1,0 determine whether the transaction was a buy or sell.

Now the problem is the values in the buys are negative, so when I tray to visualize the transactions, the values are expressed as a negative.. when it is actually just a different type of a transaction.

So in 'buy' there are multiple columns, but I need to have the values in column'amount' which are negative to their opposite sign 'positive'

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to change `amount` to its absolute value:

```
df['amount'] = np.abs(df['amount'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all values to be +ve, you need to convert the amount column to absolute value using `abs` from `numpy`, use this:

```
import numpy as np
df['amount'] = np.abs(df['amount'])
```

If you want all values to have their **opposite** sign, you can do this:

```
df['amount'] = -df['amount']
```